# Listview images quality became low

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

I was playing around with my `listbox`, but I realized because of that the images' quality suddenly dropped. The `listbox` uses an `imagelist` control to view its icons. Here is both my `listbox` and my `imagelist` properties in my designer code.

**Listview:**

```
this.listviewFiles.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Georgia", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.listviewFiles.LargeImageList = this.imageListFiles;
this.listviewFiles.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 14);
this.listviewFiles.Name = "listviewFiles";
this.listviewFiles.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(761, 392);
this.listviewFiles.TabIndex = 4;
this.listviewFiles.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.listviewFiles.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listviewFiles_SelectedIndexChnaged);
this.listviewFiles.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.listviewFiles_Click);
```

**ImageList**

```
this.imageListFiles.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageListFiles.ImageStream")));
this.imageListFiles.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.imageListFiles.Images.SetKeyName(0, "csv.ico");
this.imageListFiles.Images.SetKeyName(1, "sql.ico");
```

**Current image quality**

[image: Current image quality]

**Real quality of the picture**

[image: Real quality of the picture]

Comment: What imageList controls imageSize is set and what is original picture size?

Comment: @Reniuz both are `64x64`. And my listbox's `LargeImageList ` ColorDepth is set to `Depth32Bit`.

Comment: Your documentation is imperfect, the "real quality" image is a JPEG, I can't tell anything about the original format.  The "bad quality" image does not have the right size, I can't tell whether that's the cause of the quality loss or just a side-effect of making the screenshot.  You have to create a repro project so somebody can download it and know what it *really* looks like.

Comment: @HansPassant The real image is an `.ico` file that is `64x64` as I said and has a Bit depth of 32. If it is re-sized I would like to know where it can happen.

Comment: @HansPassant But the strange thing I just noticed in my `imagelist` is that when I first change my images they get a `PhysicalDimension ` attribute of `32x32` and when I looked again after adding them this attribute changes back to `64x64`. Could that be the reason? This attribute is readonly.

Comment: Try in code to set ColorDeph and on the next line ImageSize. If I remember correctly I had same problem and solution was to manually set properties in correct order

Comment: @Reniuz on `imagelist` or `listview` or both?

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this

```
ImageList largeImageList = new ImageList();
largeImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
largeImageList.ImageSize = new Size(64, 64); //actual size of image
largeImageList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.psd64);

ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.LargeImageList=largeImageList;
```

I think it is solve your problem forever : ))

Comment: This worked to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quality degradation of image list images when the loaded images are in PNG or in ICO format is a common problem. I've experienced it, too in a WinForm C# application.

The image list images are serialized to the .resx file of the form as Base64 encoded images and I believe there's a bug when serializing the images, because when they are serialized several times, you can definitely see the drop in quality (may be something messes up the alpha/transparency channel). Then when you remove the images from the image list and add them again, they look fine until the image list gets serialized a few times and the drop in quality becomes visible again.

I solved the problem by simply avoiding using image lists in my applications. Using an array or a dictionary of images works just as well and solves the quality degradation problem. Anothe possible solution if you still want to use image lists is to create and populate the image list at run-time and not using the designer.